# Drag div content by grabbing its background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

When the content goes outside the div, we use scrollbars to see it. How can I scroll the div content by grabbing and dragging its background? I've searched the solution but did not find what I need. Here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/xhn49e1j/

Drag any `item` to the right div and move it outside the container to the right or bottom. scrollbars appear to help you to scroll. Here is an example of what I want to achieve. See the first diagram on the link and drag it:

https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just need to detect when the mouse is down and then when the mouse is moving afterwards you can store the previous mouse coordinates and reference the current coordinates.  Finally you can scroll the div in question by an amount based on the difference in drag since the last mousemove call.

```
var mouseDown = false;
var prevCoords = { x: 0, y: 0 };

$("#mainDiv").mousedown(function() {
  mouseDown = true;
}).mousemove(function(e) {
  var currentScrollX = $('#mainDiv').scrollLeft();
  var currentScrollY = $('#mainDiv').scrollTop();
  if(mouseDown) { 
    $('#mainDiv').scrollLeft(currentScrollX + prevCoords.x - (e.clientX + currentScrollX))
    $('#mainDiv').scrollTop(currentScrollY + prevCoords.y - e.clientY)
  };
  prevCoords.x = e.clientX + currentScrollX;
  prevCoords.y = e.clientY;
}).mouseup(function() {
  mouseDown = false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6rx30muh/

**EDIT:** Fixed bug with wiggling tables when dragging:

```
            var mouseDown = false;
            var prevCoords = { x: 0, y: 0 };

            $("#mainDiv").mousedown(function() {
                mouseDown = true;
            }).mousemove(function(e) {
                var currentScrollX = $('#mainDiv').scrollLeft();
                var currentScrollY = $('#mainDiv').scrollTop();
                if(mouseDown) { 
                    $('#mainDiv').scrollLeft(currentScrollX + prevCoords.x - e.clientX)
                    $('#mainDiv').scrollTop(currentScrollY + prevCoords.y - e.clientY)
                };
                prevCoords.x = e.clientX;
                prevCoords.y = e.clientY;
            }).mouseup(function() {
                mouseDown = false;
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's what I wanted!

Comment: Just a little detail, can I reverse this scrolling? For example, If I move the mouse to the right, content should move to the right, like it is shown in the demo (see the link)

Comment: Sure just change `e.clientX - prevCoords.x` to `prevCoords.x - e.clientX` IE reverse the order of subtraction in the calculation. Side note you will need to disable it when moving the items then because it will make it UX bad for dragging.

Comment: Got it! And to finally complete and clear the answer, one more question. When the content is dragged already and I try to drag it again, the "window" of the content jumps to [0,0] coordinates. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I don't see this can you link me another fiddle example of that issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/7gvon7h1/  It starts jumping when you try to grab it again.

Comment: I will update my answer to remove some of the jitters.

Comment: Alright answer is updated you will notice that it adds the scrollX into the calculation now and makes sure to store the prev x and y every mousemove rather than the dragged ones.  There still can be some tweaks done to minimize and I would remove the behavior while dragging boxes as that UX feels uncomfortable.

Comment: It works, but a strange wiggle appears when dragging. See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/6rx30muh/3/

Comment: I fixed the bug with wiggling tables and edited your answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check for mousemove between mousedown and mouseup on the body element is a good place to start.

```
  element = $('body');
element.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
 flag = 0;
  }, false);
 element.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
    flag = 1;
   }, false);
    element.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
      if(flag === 0){
       console.log("click");
      }
    else if(flag === 1){
        console.log("drag");
   }
  }, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah, I can catch those events, but I need to know the way how to scroll the div by grabbing.